Infeasibility with scheduling_with_transitions
I am following the example in https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/contrib/scheduling_with_transitions_sat.py
If am i correct, my example below for jobs_a, each job has a single task, which can be put onto two machines. For my jobs_b alternative, I introduce an additional task with a different resource consumption for a job, so a job has two seperate tasks, which seperate resources, it becomes infeasible.
Jobs_a: feasible
Jobs_b: infeasible
Similar problem was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78242801/or-tools-cp-sat-problem-with-scheduling-with-transitions-sat-job-shop-schedul?rq=1, but that fix did not resolve my issue.
I also incread num_machines to 25 to ensure that this is not constraining.
Any pointers as to why it is infeasible? Does every job need the same number of tasks? Or does every task require a fixed number of alts? The latter is not suitable for my problem.
import argparse
import collections

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from google.protobuf import text_format

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Command line arguments.
PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
PARSER.add_argument(
    '--problem_instance', default=0, type=int, help='Problem instance.')
PARSER.add_argument(
    '--output_proto',
    default='',
    help='Output file to write the cp_model proto to.')
PARSER.add_argument('--params', default='', help='Sat solver parameters.')


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Intermediate solution printer
class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
  """Print intermediate solutions."""

  def __init__(self, makespan):
    cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
    self.__solution_count = 0
    self.__makespan = makespan

  def OnSolutionCallback(self):
    print('Solution %i, time = %f s, objective = %i, makespan = %i' %
          (self.__solution_count, self.WallTime(), self.ObjectiveValue(),
           self.Value(self.__makespan)))
    self.__solution_count += 1


def main(args):
  """Solves the scheduling with transitions problem."""

  instance = args.problem_instance
  instance = 0
  parameters = args.params
  output_proto = args.output_proto

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Data.
  jobs_a = [[[(100, 0, 'R6'), (2, 1, 'R6')]],
                [[(2, 0, 'R3'), (100, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(100, 0, 'R1'), (16, 1, 'R1')]],
                [[(1, 0, 'R1'), (38, 1, 'R1')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R1'), (10, 1,  'R1')]],
                [[(16, 0, 'R3'), (17, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (14, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (15, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (13, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(100, 0, 'R1'), (38, 1, 'R1')]]]
  
  
  # jobs with multiple subtasks
  jobs_b = [[[(100, 0, 'R6'), (2, 1, 'R6')], [(3, 2, 'R4')]],
                [[(2, 0, 'R3'), (100, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(100, 0, 'R1'), (16, 1, 'R1')]],
                [[(1, 0, 'R1'), (38, 1, 'R1')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R1'), (10, 1,  'R1')]],
                [[(16, 0, 'R3'), (17, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (14, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (15, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (13, 1, 'R3')]],
                [[(100, 0, 'R1'), (38, 1, 'R1')]]]
  
  

           
           


  large_jobs = [
      [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (10, 1, 'R1')]], [[(9, 0, 'R3'),  (22, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (13, 1, 'R3')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (38, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (38, 1, 'R3')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (16, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (11, 1, 'R3')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (13, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R3'), (-1, 1, 'R3')]], [[(13, 0, 'R3'), (-1, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (15, 1, 'R3')]], [[(12, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(14, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]], [[(13, 0, 'R3'), (-1, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (15, 1, 'R3')]], [[(14, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R3'), (-1, 1, 'R3')]], [[(14, 0, 'R3'), (-1, 1, 'R3')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]], [[(15, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R2'), (16, 1, 'R2')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R2'), (16, 1, 'R2')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (27, 1, 'R5')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (13, 1, 'R5')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (13, 1, 'R5')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (13, 1, 'R5')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (17, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(16, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(16, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(16, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(16, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]], [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(12, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]], [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (14, 1, 'R5')]], [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(14, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (21, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (21, 1, 'R1')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (21, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R6'), (-1, 1, 'R6')]], [[(13, 0, 'R2'), (-1, 1, 'R2')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R6'), (12, 1, 'R6')]], [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R1'), (-1, 1, 'R1')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R6'), (14, 1, 'R6')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (5, 1, 'R5')]], [[(3, 0, 'R2'), (-1, 1, 'R2')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (21, 1, 'R1')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (21, 1, 'R1')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R1'), (21, 1, 'R1')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R5'), (1, 1, 'R5')]],
      [[(1, 0, 'R2'), (-1, 1, 'R2')]], [[(-1, 0, 'R2'), (19, 1, 'R2')]],
      [[(13, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]], [[(12, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(-1, 0, 'R3'), (2, 1, 'R3')]], [[(11, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]],
      [[(6, 0, 'R6'), (-1, 1, 'R6')]], [[(6, 0, 'R6'), (-1, 1, 'R6')]],
      [[(1, 0, 'R2'), (-1, 1, 'R2')]], [[(12, 0, 'R4'), (-1, 1, 'R4')]]
  ]

  #jobs = tmp_jobs if instance == 1 else large_jobs
  jobs = jobs_a if instance == 1 else jobs_b

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Helper data.
  num_jobs = len(jobs)
  all_jobs = range(num_jobs)
  num_machines = 25
  all_machines = range(num_machines)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Model.
  model = cp_model.CpModel()

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Compute a maximum makespan greedily.
  horizon = 0
  for job in jobs:
    for task in job:
      max_task_duration = 0
      for alternative in task:
        max_task_duration = max(max_task_duration, alternative[0])
      horizon += max_task_duration

  print('Horizon = %i' % horizon)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Global storage of variables.
  intervals_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  presences_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  starts_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  ends_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  resources_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  ranks_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)

  job_starts = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
  job_presences = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id, alt_id).
  job_ranks = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id, alt_id).
  job_ends = []  # indexed by job_id

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Scan the jobs and create the relevant variables and intervals.
  for job_id in all_jobs:
    job = jobs[job_id]
    num_tasks = len(job)
    previous_end = 0

    for task_id in range(num_tasks):
      task = job[task_id]
      
      print(task)

      min_duration = task[0][0]
      max_duration = task[0][0]

      num_alternatives = len(task)
      all_alternatives = range(num_alternatives)

      for alt_id in range(1, num_alternatives):
        alt_duration = task[alt_id][0]
        min_duration = min(min_duration, alt_duration)
        max_duration = max(max_duration, alt_duration)

      # Create main interval for the task.
      suffix_name = '_j%i_t%i' % (job_id, task_id)
      start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + suffix_name)
      duration = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                                 'duration' + suffix_name)
      end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix_name)
      

      # Store the start for the solution.
      job_starts[(job_id, task_id)] = start

      # Add precedence with previous task in the same job.
      #if previous_end:
      model.Add(start >= previous_end)
      previous_end = end

      # Create alternative intervals.
      l_presences = []
      for alt_id in all_alternatives:
        ### add to link interval with eqp constraint.
        ### process time = -1 cannot be processed at this machine.
        if jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0] == -1:
          continue
        alt_suffix = '_j%i_t%i_a%i' % (job_id, task_id, alt_id)
        l_presence = model.NewBoolVar('presence' + alt_suffix)
        l_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + alt_suffix)
        l_duration = task[alt_id][0]
        l_end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + alt_suffix)
        
        l_interval = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
            l_start, l_duration, l_end, l_presence, 'interval' + alt_suffix)
        
        
        l_rank = model.NewIntVar(-1, 100, 'rank' + alt_suffix)
        
        l_presences.append(l_presence)
        l_machine = task[alt_id][1]
        l_type = task[alt_id][2]

        # Link the original variables with the local ones.
        model.Add(start == l_start).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
        model.Add(duration == l_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
        model.Add(end == l_end).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)

        # Add the local variables to the right machine.
        intervals_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_interval)
        starts_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_start)
        ends_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_end)
        presences_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_presence)
        resources_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_type)
        ranks_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_rank)

        # Store the variables for the solution.
        job_presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)] = l_presence
        job_ranks[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)] = l_rank

      # Only one machine can process each lot.
      model.Add(sum(l_presences) == 1)

    job_ends.append(previous_end)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Create machines constraints nonoverlap process
  for machine_id in all_machines:
    intervals = intervals_per_machines[machine_id]
    if len(intervals) > 1:
      model.AddNoOverlap(intervals)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Transition times and transition costs using a circuit constraint.
  switch_literals = []
  for machine_id in all_machines:
      
    # if none assigned, pass
    if len(starts_per_machines[machine_id]) == 0:
        continue
      
        
    machine_starts = starts_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_ends = ends_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_presences = presences_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_resources = resources_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_ranks = ranks_per_machines[machine_id]
    intervals = intervals_per_machines[machine_id]
    arcs = []
    num_machine_tasks = len(machine_starts)
    all_machine_tasks = range(num_machine_tasks)

    for i in all_machine_tasks:
      # Initial arc from the dummy node (0) to a task.
      start_lit = model.NewBoolVar('')
      arcs.append([0, i + 1, start_lit])
      # If this task is the first, set both rank and start to 0.
      model.Add(machine_ranks[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)
      model.Add(machine_starts[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)
      # Final arc from an arc to the dummy node.
      arcs.append([i + 1, 0, model.NewBoolVar('')])
      # Self arc if the task is not performed.
      arcs.append([i + 1, i + 1, machine_presences[i].Not()])
      model.Add(machine_ranks[i] == -1).OnlyEnforceIf(
          machine_presences[i].Not())

      for j in all_machine_tasks:
        if i == j:
          continue

        lit = model.NewBoolVar('%i follows %i' % (j, i))
        arcs.append([i + 1, j + 1, lit])
        model.AddImplication(lit, machine_presences[i])
        model.AddImplication(lit, machine_presences[j])

        # Maintain rank incrementally.
        model.Add(machine_ranks[j] == machine_ranks[i] + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)

        # Compute the transition time if task j is the successor of task i.
        if machine_resources[i] != machine_resources[j]:
          transition_time = 3
          switch_literals.append(lit)
        else:
          transition_time = 0
        # We add the reified transition to link the literals with the times
        # of the tasks.
        model.Add(machine_starts[j] == machine_ends[i] +
                  transition_time).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
    if arcs:
        model.AddCircuit(arcs)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Objective.
  makespan = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
  model.AddMaxEquality(makespan, job_ends)
  makespan_weight = 1
  transition_weight = 5
  model.Minimize(makespan * makespan_weight +
                 sum(switch_literals) * transition_weight)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Write problem to file.
  if output_proto:
    print('Writing proto to %s' % output_proto)
    with open(output_proto, 'w') as text_file:
      text_file.write(str(model))

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Solve.
  solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
  solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 10
  solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
  if parameters:
    text_format.Merge(parameters, solver.parameters)
  solution_printer = SolutionPrinter(makespan)
  status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Print solution.
  if status == cp_model.FEASIBLE or status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    for job_id in all_jobs:
      for task_id in range(len(jobs[job_id])):
        start_value = solver.Value(job_starts[(job_id, task_id)])
        machine = 0
        duration = 0
        select = 0
        rank = -1

        for alt_id in range(len(jobs[job_id][task_id])):
          if jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0] == -1:
            continue

          if solver.BooleanValue(job_presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)]):
            duration = jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0]
            machine = jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][1]
            select = alt_id
            rank = solver.Value(job_ranks[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)])

        print(
            '  Job %i starts at %i (alt %i, duration %i) with rank %i on machine %i'
            % (job_id, start_value, select, duration, rank, machine))

    print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Objective value: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    print('Makespan: %i' % solver.Value(makespan))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(PARSER.parse_args())


You need to understand my code instead of blindly copying it.

you need to remove all the ranking code as this is not useful.
There is a specific line that only works if all jobs have only one task:

      # If this task is the first, set  start to 0.
      model.Add(machine_starts[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)

if you remove it, it works fine.

Here is the result:

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 79
best_bound: 79
integers: 0
booleans: 0
conflicts: 0
branches: 0
propagations: 0
integer_propagations: 0
restarts: 0
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.141397
usertime: 0.141397
deterministic_time: 0.290054
gap_integral: 0.0815429
solution_fingerprint: 0x9d5601ec44dbdee7

  Job 0 starts at 0 (alt 1, duration 2 on machine 1
  Job 0 starts at 36 (alt 0, duration 3 on machine 2
  Job 1 starts at 30 (alt 0, duration 2 on machine 0
  Job 2 starts at 43 (alt 1, duration 16 on machine 1
  Job 3 starts at 63 (alt 0, duration 1 on machine 0
  Job 4 starts at 59 (alt 1, duration 10 on machine 1
  Job 5 starts at 14 (alt 0, duration 16 on machine 0
  Job 6 starts at 32 (alt 0, duration 14 on machine 0
  Job 7 starts at 0 (alt 0, duration 14 on machine 0
  Job 8 starts at 46 (alt 0, duration 14 on machine 0
  Job 9 starts at 5 (alt 1, duration 38 on machine 1
Solve status: OPTIMAL
Objective value: 79
Makespan: 69


There is a nicer example to start from to manage transitions.

